# Mongoose - RangeError: Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to bulk insert documents into MongoDB (so bypassing Mongoose and using the native driver instead as Mongoose doesn't support bulk insert of an array of documents).  The reason I'm doing this is to improve the speed of writing.

I am receiving the error "RangeError: Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded" at console.log(err) in the code below:

```
function _fillResponses(globalSurvey, optionsToSelectRegular, optionsToSelectPiped, responseIds, callback) {
  Response.find({'_id': {$in: responseIds}}).exec(function(err, responses) {
    if (err) { return callback(err); }

    if (globalSurvey.questions.length) {
      responses.forEach(function(response) {
        console.log("Filling response: " + response._id);
        response.answers = [];
        globalAnswers = {};
        globalSurvey.questions.forEach(function(question) {
          ans = _getAnswer(question, optionsToSelectRegular, optionsToSelectPiped, response);
          globalAnswers[question._id] = ans;
          response.answers.push(ans);
        });
      });
      Response.collection.insert(responses, function(err, responsesResult) {
        console.log(err);
        callback()
      });
    } else {
        callback();
      }
  });
}
```

So similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356859/mongoose-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded

Perhaps it's something about the format of the responses array that Mongoose returns that means I can't directly insert using MongoDB natively?  I've tried .toJSON() on each response but no luck.

I still get the error even with a very small amount of data but looping through and calling the Mongoose save on each document individually works fine.

EDIT: I think it is related to this issue: http://howtosjava.blogspot.com.au/2012/05/nodejs-mongoose-rangeerror-maximum-call.html

My schema for responses is:

```
var ResponseSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  randomUUID: String,
  status: String,
  submitted: Date,
  initialEmailId: String,
  survey: String,
  answers: [AnswerSchema]
});
```

So, answers are a sub-document within responses.  Not sure how to fix it though....

Comment: Probably unrelated, but `callback()` is called twice if `globalSurvey.questions` is not empty. Call the last `callback()` in an `else` statement: `} else { callback(); }`.

Comment: Thanks - yep agree but think it's unrelated....haven't got past the insert yet.

Comment: I have edited to fix that issue.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I was having this same issue and I started digging through the mongoose source code (version 3.8.14).  Eventually it led me to this line within

- mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection/core.js -> *insert*(...) -> *insertWithWriteCommands*(...) ->
- mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection/batch/ordered.js -> *bulk.insert(docs[i])* -> *addToOperationsList(...)* -> *bson.calculateObjectSize(document, false);*

  var bsonSize = bson.calculateObjectSize(document, false);

Apparently, this calls BSON.calculateObjectSize, which calls calculateObjectSize which then infinitely recurses.  I wasn't able to dig that far in to what caused it, but figured that it may have something to do with the mongoose wrapper binding functions to the Schema.  Since I was inserting raw data into mongoDB, once I decided to change the bulk insert in mongoose to a standard javascript object, the problem went away and bulk inserts happened correctly.  You might be able to do something similar.

Essentially, my code went from

```
//EDIT: mongoose.model needs lowercase 'm' for getter method

var myModel = mongoose.model('MyCollection');
var toInsert = myModel();
var array = [toInsert];
myModel.collection.insert(array, {}, function(err, docs) {});
```

to

```
//EDIT: mongoose.model needs lowercase 'm' for getter method

var myModel = mongoose.model('MyCollection');
var toInsert = { //stuff in here 
   name: 'john',
   date: new Date()
};
var array = [toInsert];
myModel.collection.insert(array, {}, function(err, docs) {});
```

Comment: Just to add some clarification to this answer, the problem can be resolved by: 1. don't use a schema instance for the bulk insert 2: instead, use a plain old JSON object.

Answer (score 23):

Confirmed, but not a bug. `Model.collection.insert()` bypasses Mongoose and so you're telling the node driver to insert an object that contains mongoose internals like `$__`, etc. The stack overflow is probably because bson is trying to compute the size of an object that references itself indirectly.

Long story short, use `Document.toObject()`, that's what its for: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject

```
Response.find({}).exec(function(err, responses) {
  if (err) { 
    return callback(err); 
  }

  if (true) {
    var toInsert = [];
    responses.forEach(function(response) {
      console.log("Filling response: " + response._id);
      response.answers = [];
      [{ name: 'test' }].forEach(function(ans) {
        response.answers.push(ans);
      });
      toInsert.push(response.toObject());
    });
    Response.collection.insert(toInsert, function(err, responsesResult) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  } else {
      callback();
    }
});
```

Also, the code you specified won't work even if you fix the stack overflow. Since you're trying to `insert()` docs that are already in the database, all the inserts will fail because of `_id` conflicts. You'd really be much better off just using a stream() to read the results one at a time and then `save()` them back into the db.

Comment: Thank you Valeri! Reference: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1961#event-242694964

Comment: I encountered the same thing when using bulk insert. it works like a charm. thank you. why using mongoose object in bulk insert will cause the problem?

Answer (score 6):

guys! I've faced that weird error today. It happened because of I had a Schema with `ref` properties and tried to pass in `create`/`update` whole related document. I've changed argument to `_id` only and that did the trick. Works like a charm. I found the answer [here](http://www.pressinganswer.com/1754765/node-js-mongoose-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded) (scroll down to `February 21, 2013, 8:05 pm gustavohenke` comment).

Comment: Thanks, this was definitely my problem, unlike some of the other issues here.

Comment: This should be the valid answer than pivoting from mongoose. Thanks man!

Comment: Thank you, had exactly same issue when cloning multiple data and changing whole document to just _id resolve the issue.

Comment: I also saw the opposite where having an _id field in your document caused this loop. I had added that to get better typechecking, removal fixed my issue. YMMV :)

Comment: Thanks so much! it this really helped!

Comment: Thanks, this should be a valid answer! I changed my PUT function from passing the _id in the body to params so now I'm calling /:id and passing the body without _id and it works.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced similar issue.

```
//manyvalues is array of objects
schema.methods.somemethod = function(manyvalues,callback) {
    this.model(collection).collection.insertMany(manyvalues,callback);
}
```

But this caused error **[RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded]**.
So I have created new model from *manyvalues* and used it as below and it worked.

```
schema.methods.somemethod = function(manyvalues,callback){
     var list = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(manyvalues));//created a new object.
     this.model(collection).collection.insertMany(list,callback);
}
```

The problem may be caused if *manyvalues* is changed internally.

Comment: Great,iIt helps me - in my case problem was that I was trying to findOneAndUpdate with object that contains typescript class transpiled to ES2016 class instance (so most probably problem will also occur using just class instance).

Answer (score 1):

This also happens if there's a duplication of of the `_id` value. Most situations will be when you might create an new record from an existing record.

Deleting the `_id` and inserting the record and letting Mongoose/MongoDb take care of the creation of the id.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Mongoose version is `5.13.14`. My stack trace is:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at minimize (...\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:3564:18)
    at minimize (...\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:3576:18)
    at minimize (...\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:3576:18)
    at minimize (...\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:3576:18)
    at minimize (...\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:3576:18)
    at minimize (...\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:3576:18)
    at minimize (...\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:3576:18)
```

I found 2 ways to fix the issue:

1. Using `toObject()` method:

```
const model = await MyModel.findOne(conditions);
return model?.toObject();
```

2. Using `minimize: false` in `toJSON` option of the schema:

```
export const MySchema = new Schema({
    ...
}, {
    ...
    toJSON: {
        getters: true,
        // !!! HERE !!!
        minimize: false,
    },
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for circular references in the responses object. I Faced a similar issue due to circular references.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the error `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.`
This occurred when I was trying to save the list of an object inside a field. What I figured out was you should not pass the list as it is.

I had a model called `Order` that accepts List of `Items`.
Break down the whole process into two steps:

1. Simply create your `Order` model without the lists
2. use `.findByIdAndUpdate`

```
    const order = await OrderModel.create({
                  status: "initiated",
                  createdAt: new Date(),
                });

    await OrderModel.findByIdAndUpdate(order, {
              $push: {
                items: cartItems,
              },
            });
```

Here items is the field inside the model that accepts a list of items.
this way, you won't get the issue of Maximum Stack size exceeded. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, it was that I was querying a field that didn't exist in the schema using the $ne(other query operators may have a similar problem)

```
var TestSchema = new Schema({
  test:[]
});
...
models.Test.findOne({"test2": {$ne: "t"} })...
```

In the example above I am testing for test2 instead of test