# Mongoose - Insert two collections : one is ID dependant of the other

Tags: node.js, mongodb, collections, insert, mongoose

I have an array of objects I want insert in my DB:

```
        tracks = [new Track({name : "myname1"}), new Track({name : "myname2"})]

        Track.collection.insert(tracks, {}, function(err, tracks){   
             console.log('err', err);
        }
```

But even with 2 objects in the array, the insert() method throw an error :

```
[RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded]
```

(The "tracks" doc is created, but nothing inside it.)

**EDIT** 
[Mongoose - RangeError: Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466366/mongoose-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded) solve the first problem but not solve my real problem:

When you create an object from a Model, you can get the _id, which I use to create an other object. But is not possible to insert a collection of Mongoose object, as the solved question: **You have to use an array JSON object ONLY**.

```
data.items.forEach(function(item,index){
    tracks.push(new Track({name : "myname1"}) );
    posts.push(new Post({trackId : track._id}) );
}

Track.collection.insert(tracks, {}, function(err, tracks){   
         console.log('err', err);
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mongoose - RangeError: Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466366/mongoose-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found is to create my own unique Id rather to get the ID of a mongoose Object ...and use a JSON object:

```
data.items.forEach(function(item,index){
    tracks.push({name : "myname1"}) ); //name is unique
    posts.push({trackId : track.name) );
}

Track.create(tracks, function(err){   
         console.log('err', err);
}
```