# Store huge Array of JSON data in MongoDB via Mongoose

Tags: node.js, algorithm, mongoose

Let's say I have an JavaScript Array `companyBills` and inside of it I have **m** objects stored in such manner; with `m > 100.000` elements.

```
{key_0:value_0, key_1:value_0_1, key_n:value_0_n},
{key_0:value_1, key_1:value_1_1, key_n:value_1_n},
{key_0:value_m, key_1:value_m_1, key_n:value_m_n}
```

Now I want to store this in MongoDB via Mongoose, in such a manner:

```
CompanyBills.create (companyBills, function(err, jellybean, snickers) {
        if(!err) {          
          console.log('Success');
        } else {
          console.log('Error');
        }
```

However the array `companyBills` is too huge. Thus I want to store in chunks of **1/100 m**. How to split the array `companyBills` Time-efficiently and store in MongoDB?

I am creating the array with https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx, maybe there is an opportunity to hook-in early.

Comment: Can you post the code of array creation? If you don't mind the order of inserted data you can divide array into chunks and use `async` library for put each chunk into the db in parallel

Comment: There is indeed a solution to this particular scenario: https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues/138 However I would be very interested in the async library for parallel access.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the bulk insert method?

```
CompanyBills.collection.insert([huge array], function (err, results) {
    Console.log(results)
})
```

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/insert-documents/

Comment: Looks like that is the cuprit, there is no bulk write method in Mongoose as of now; see https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/2366, so the `create` method I used is very slow, inserting each element on its own. Thus I have to use the underlying MongoDB driver.

Comment: Its very easy to access to driver directly by using CompanyBill.collection.insert(). Edited above

Comment: Confirmed this *would* be a solution, if not for a new bug rendering the native driver bulk insert option useless - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466366/mongoose-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded Maybe you can confirm?